# Node.js Express DELETE route not working

Tags: node.js, express, routes

When trying to delete an item it returns: cannot GET /posts

routes.js

```
app.delete('/posts/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log("Deleting");
    Post.findById( req.params.id, function ( err, post ){
        post.remove( function ( err, post ){
            res.render('posts.ejs');
        });
    });
});
```

posts.ejs

```
<% posts.forEach( function( post ){ %>
                <p><%= post._id %></p>
                <p><%= post.title %></p>
                <p><%= post.content %></p>
                <a href="/posts/<%= post._id %>" method='delete'>Delete</a>
            <% }); %>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML `a` element doesn't have `method` attribute. Check the [legal attributes list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2). That means links are always `GET`.

If you want to send a `DELETE` request using the browser your only option is to use `ajax`.

Comment: You can use some Rest Clients for testing your API calls